# Python error "ImportError: No module named"

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

Python is installed in a local directory.

My directory tree looks like this:

```
(local directory)/site-packages/toolkit/interface.py
```

My code is in here:

```
(local directory)/site-packages/toolkit/examples/mountain.py
```

To run the example, I write `python mountain.py`, and in the code I have:

```
from toolkit.interface import interface
```

And I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mountain.py", line 28, in ?
    from toolkit.interface import interface
ImportError: No module named toolkit.interface
```

I have already checked `sys.path` and there I have the directory `/site-packages`. Also, I have the file `__init__.py.bin` in the toolkit folder to indicate to Python that this is a package. I also have a `__init__.py.bin` in the examples directory.

I do not know why Python cannot find the file when it is in `sys.path`.  Any ideas?  Can it be a permissions problem?  Do I need some execution permission?

Comment: Check that you have read permission to that file from python.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20999950/1657225

Comment: Please be sure to mark your directory as "Resources Root" to let PyCharm know this is a package.

Comment: The problem in my case was that there was the permission to newly installed modules were not `755`. That was because `umask` on the machine was `0027` due to which the `others` did not have `read` permission causing module to not be read. Adding `read` permission fixed my problem. It's worth checking the permission of the target directory post-installation.

Comment: Try to blow url :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887614/how-to-import-module-or-a-file-from-subfolder-in-python/47887660#47887660

Comment: maybe local directory name is `interface`  (have been a conflict).

Comment: check things like: is python2 being used instead of 3? Do you files have the proper line ending configured? Are packages properly declared?

Comment: The issue described here is extremely out of date, and the problem in OP's case could not actually be diagnosed from the information that was actually provided in the question. `__init__.py` hasn't been necessary since Python 3.3 for relative imports, and I can't think of a reason it would ever have been required for absolute imports. Absolutely mind-boggling that this nonsense has millions of views.

Comment: (The given information also doesn't illustrate the actual directory tree nor `sys.path` accurately enough to be sure of understanding the problem. In particular, I can't fathom what the "local directory" might be, but that sounds unlikely to be a place that makes sense to contain the `site-packages` sub-directory.)

Answer (score 326, accepted):

Based on your comments to orip's post, I guess this is what happened:

1. You edited `__init__.py` on windows.
2. The windows editor added something non-printing, perhaps a carriage-return (end-of-line in Windows is CR/LF; in unix it is LF only), or perhaps a CTRL-Z (windows end-of-file).
3. You used WinSCP to copy the file to your unix box.
4. WinSCP thought: "This has something that's not basic text; I'll put a .bin extension to indicate binary data."
5. The missing `__init__.py` (now called `__init__.py.bin`) means python doesn't understand toolkit as a package.
6. You create `__init__.py` in the appropriate directory and everything works... ?

Comment: Also, python -c 'import sys; print sys.path' helps -- sometimes the user has placed the files in a path not scanned.

Comment: I'm using the same thing except WinSCP didn't append `.bin`.

Comment: if I have a empty "\_\_init\_\_.py" will the same thing happen?

Comment: For me the issue was I was using `python driver.py` when I should have been using `python3 driver.py` since I installed with `pip3`.

Comment: As @EricWiener pointed out, using python 2 may cause this issue aswell. He may be using #!/usr/bin/env python to detect the python environment, and have python2 instead of python3 mapped, which causes that error in some packages

Comment: to add @mikebabcock comment, from the path, in my case, there is precedent path containing the folder that masks the actual folder I intend to use.

Comment: `__init__.py` is **not needed** since 3.3 (although it has some other effects and is often desirable). See https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/.

Answer (score 106):

I ran into something very similar when I did this exercise in LPTHW; I could never get Python to recognise that I had files in the directory I was calling from. But I was able to get it to work in the end. What I did, and what I recommend, is to try this:

(NOTE: From your initial post, I am assuming you are using an *NIX-based machine and are running things from the command line, so this advice is tailored to that. Since I run Ubuntu, this is what I did)

1. Change directory (cd) to the directory *above* the directory where your files are. In this case, you're trying to run the `mountain.py` file, and trying to call the `toolkit.interface.py` module, which are in separate directories. In this case, you would go to the directory that contains paths to both those files (or in other words, the closest directory that the paths of both those files share). Which in this case is the `toolkit` directory.
2. When you are in the `toolkit` directory, enter this line of code on your command line:

   `export PYTHONPATH=.`

   This sets your PYTHONPATH to ".", which basically means that your PYTHONPATH will now look for any called files within the directory you are currently in, (and more to the point, in the *sub-directory branches* of the directory you are in. So it doesn't just look in your current directory, but in all the directories that are **in** your current directory).
3. After you've set your PYTHONPATH in the step above, run your module from your current directory (the `toolkit` directory). Python should now find and load the modules you specified.

Comment: Or on Windows `set PYTHONPATH=.`.

Comment: Be careful if you have third party or custom library references in an already existing `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. If you do the instead run: `set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;.;` to append `.` to the `PYTHONPATH` and then `echo %PYTHONPATH%` which should display `path\to\custom\library;.;`. Then run your application from the application directory with `python applicationlaunchfile.py`.

Comment: You saved me. Thanks! This also works for Python 3.10 in 2022.

Comment: Reason why `.` is not in PYTHONPATH by default: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435697/python-is-the-current-directory-automatically-included-in-path#comment105432715_24435742

Answer (score 97):

Does

```
(local directory)/site-packages/toolkit
```

have a `__init__.py`?

To make import *walk* through your directories every directory must have a `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Good point! Remark: Since Python 3.3, any directory on sys.path with a name that matches the package name will be recognised.

Comment: isn't this only necessary for relative path references? why **must** every directory have it ?

Comment: `__init__.py` is **not needed** since 3.3 (although it has some other effects and is often desirable). See https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/.

Answer (score 47):

On *nix, also make sure that PYTHONPATH is configured correctly, especially that it has this format:

```
 .:/usr/local/lib/python
```

(Mind the `.:` at the beginning, so that it can search on the current directory, too.)

It may also be in other locations, depending on the version:

```
 .:/usr/lib/python
 .:/usr/lib/python2.6
 .:/usr/lib/python2.7 and etc.
```

Comment: It may also be `.:/usr/lib/python`, `.:/usr/lib/python2.6`, `.:/usr/lib/python2.7` and etc. depending on the version

Comment: For me, the module is in in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages but when I type python3 in the terminal (ubuntu), and try to import it, it doesn't allow me, saying that it doesn't exist. "ImportError: no module x exists"

Comment: Adding `#!/usr/bin/python` at the end of a file should work too, right?

Comment: @Nearoo I don't think that will work. Plus usually this shebang is added at the top of a file.

Comment: **-1 Having Python installation directory listed in PYTHONPATH is plainly wrong and shows lack of understanding of what this variable is meant for.**

Comment: On MacOSX fixed it by adding PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages to startup scripts.

Answer (score 46):

You are reading this answer says that your `__init__.py` is in the right place, you have installed all the dependencies and you are still getting the `ImportError`.

I was facing a similar issue except that my program would run fine when ran using PyCharm but the above error when I would run it from the terminal. After digging further, I found out that `PYTHONPATH` didn't have the entry for the project directory. So, I set `PYTHONPATH` per [Import statement works on PyCharm but not from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40304117/608639):

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`  (OR your project root directory)
```

There's another way to do this using `sys.path` as:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'<project directory>') OR
sys.path.append('<project directory>')
```

You can use insert/append based on the order in which you want your project to be searched.

Comment: This is what I did as a workaround. But I still don't understand why this should be necessary. I have, in my Pipfile, a relative path module that cannot be detected (e.g. I get the ImportError) without said workaround.

Comment: This is great. A general way to apply it if you're sure you're in the right path: ```sys.path.append(os.getcwd())```

Answer (score 34):

Using **PyCharm** (part of the JetBrains suite) you need to define your script directory as Source:
Right Click > Mark Directory as > Sources Root

Comment: thank you, this is definitely needed inheriting legacy projects with all modules in a flat hierarchy outside of a /src directory

Answer (score 26):

I solved my own problem, and I will write a summary of the things that were wrong and the solution:

The file needs to be called exactly `__init__.py`. If the extension is different such as in my case `.py.bin` then Python cannot move through the directories and then it cannot find the modules. To edit the files you need to use a Linux editor, such as [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) or [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano). If you use a Windows editor this will write some hidden characters.

Another problem that was affecting it was that I had another Python version installed by the root, so if someone is working with a local installation of python, be sure that the Python installation that is running the programs is the local Python. To check this, just do `which python`, and see if the executable is the one that is in your local directory. If not, change the path, but be sure that the local Python directory is before than the other Python.

Comment: A problem I got was that a module was (re)installed by pip with only the root user to access it, so the user that ran the program didn't see it.

Comment: @JānisElmeris can you elaborate more on the above comment, I think I am also facing a similar error. I have my `__init__.py` files placed in relevant directory but I manually installed a package using `setup.py`. How did installing a new package would interfere imports.

Comment: @darth_coder, sorry, that was six years ago and I don't remember the case. Also, I'm dealing with Python very little, not at all lately. From what I wrote, I can just think that I installed a package as root, which changed the permissions so that other users didn't have the access they had before.

Answer (score 26):

For me, it was something really stupid. I installed the library using `pip3 install` but was running my program as `python program.py` as opposed to `python3 program.py`.

Comment: Thank you! Think this is a common mistake if you're running on a system that has Python2 installed by default (OS X)

Answer (score 21):

an easy solution is to install the module using `python -m pip install <library-name>` instead of `pip install <library-name>`
you may use sudo in case of admin restrictions

Comment: What does `python -m` achieve in front of `pip install`?

Comment: @sporc - when you use the -m command-line flag, Python will import a module or package for you and then run it as a script. When you don't use the -m flag, the file you named is run as just a script.

Comment: Not sure what this answer is trying to say wrt `python -m pip...` working, but `pip...` did not: they are effectively the same thing, assuming they're actually in the same `python` directory.  Possibly, the observed situation was that the stand-alone `pip` program wasn't available in some older python release (but it is now in latest 2.7 & 3.x).  In that case, the `python` was in a local virtualenv and `pip` wasn't, so `python -m pip install` would install in the local virtualenv, whereas `pip` would try to install in the system python (and fail w/o sudo). In any case, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 19):

To mark a directory as a package you need a file named `__init__.py`.

Comment: I already have a file called __init__.py.bin, If I change the name to __init__.py, then I get this error:

/__init__.py", line 1
    "utilities", "demo"]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What's in __init__.py?  Post that as part of your question, please.

Comment: There is nothing, it is empty, It was with the package that I download, do I need to write something in the file?.

Comment: @S.Lott: you don't need to put anything in your __init__.py right?

Comment: @Eduardo.  Your __init__.py gets an error.  And you say it's empty.  That's difficult to reconcile.  And it can't be called __init__.py.bin -- Python would ignore this file.  Typically, it can have nothing in it.

Comment: You were right Lott I edited the file with a windows editor and it wrote some hide characters, now I have create new files with vi.

Comment: @Eduardo: You may want to get Programmer's Notepad or Komodo Edit or something that edits pure text with no hidden special characters.  They may be easier to use than vi.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I usually use nano for edition, the reason why I used a windows editor is because I am working in a cluster, and I use WinSCP to move files and sometimes I use that editor for change files.

Answer (score 8):

To all those who still have this issue. I believe Pycharm gets confused with imports. For me, when i write 'from namespace import something', the previous line gets underlined in red, signaling that there is an error, but works. However ''from .namespace import something' doesn't get underlined, but also doesn't work.

Try

```
try:
    from namespace import something 
except NameError:
    from .namespace import something
```

Comment: The first is python 2 syntax, the second is python 3.

Comment: @TanyaBranagan no, that is simply incorrect. `from namespace import something` is an absolute import, and `from .namespace import something` is a relative import. Both can work in either Python 2 or Python 3; each requires separate setup. In Python 2.4, the absolute import syntax used to try relative imports first, and the relative import syntax hadn't been implemented yet. But in 2019 it was rare for anyone to be stuck even on 2.6; Python 2.7 was synonymous with "Python 2" for years.

Answer (score 7):

Yup. You need the directory to contain the `__init__.py` file, which is the file that initializes the package. Here, have a look at [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

> The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, __init__.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the __all__ variable, described later.

Answer (score 7):

If you have tried all methods provided above but failed, maybe your module has **the same name** as a built-in module. Or, a module with **the same name** existing in a folder that has a high priority in `sys.path` than your module's.

To debug, say your `from foo.bar import baz` complaints `ImportError: No module named bar`. Changing to `import foo; print foo`, which will show the path of `foo`. Is it what you expect?

If not, Either rename `foo` or use [absolute imports](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328).

Comment: For me, this yields `ImportError: No module named foo`.

Answer (score 6):

My two cents:

[image]

Spit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "bash\bash.py", line 454, in main
        import bosh
      File "Wrye Bash Launcher.pyw", line 63, in load_module
        mod = imp.load_source(fullname,filename+ext,fp)
      File "bash\bosh.py", line 69, in <module>
        from game.oblivion.RecordGroups import MobWorlds, MobDials, MobICells, \
    ImportError: No module named RecordGroups
```

This confused the hell out of me - went through posts and posts suggesting ugly syspath hacks (as you see my `__init__.py` were all there). Well turns out that game/oblivion.py and game/oblivion was confusing python
which spit out the rather unhelpful "No module named RecordGroups". I'd be interested in a workaround and/or links documenting this (same name) behavior -> EDIT (2017.01.24) - have a look at [What If I Have a Module and a Package With The Same Name?](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/packages/) Interestingly normally *packages* take precedence but apparently our launcher violates this.

EDIT (2015.01.17): I did not mention we use a [custom launcher](https://github.com/wrye-bash/wrye-bash/blob/dev/Mopy/Wrye%20Bash%20Launcher.pyw#L47-L80) dissected [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193586/file-string-in-python-traceback/27202474#27202474).

Comment: more like the path is off. `game.oblivion.RecordGroups !== game/oblivion/patchers/RecordGroups.py`

May want to fix that with appending your python code to use: `game.oblivion.patchers.RecordGroups`

Comment: @DwightSpencer: I am sure I imported the "RecordGroups" in `game.oblivion.__init__.py` but may have to check this

Answer (score 6):

For me, running the file as a module helped.

Instead of

```
python myapp/app.py
```

using

```
python -m myapp.app
```

It's not exactly the same but it might be a better approach in some cases.

Comment: I don't know what `myapp\app` vs `myapp/app` vs `myapp/app.py` vs `myapp\app.py` vs `myapp.app` means, but this fixed it.

Comment: same for me, I don't know what the differences are, perhaps I should figure it out but this fixed it for me too

Answer (score 5):

1. You must have the file __ init__.py in the same directory where it's the file that you are importing.
2. You can not try to import a file that has the same name and be a file from 2 folders configured on the PYTHONPATH.

eg:
/etc/environment

PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/folder1:/opt/folder2

/opt/folder1/foo

/opt/folder2/foo

And, if you are trying to import foo file, python will not know which one you want.

from foo import ...   >>> importerror: no module named foo

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the problem was I was linking to *debug* `python` & `boost::Python`, which requires that the extension be `FooLib_d.pyd`, not just `FooLib.pyd`; renaming the file or updating `CMakeLists.txt` properties fixed the error.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed my issue by writing `print (sys.path)` and found out that python was using out of date packages despite a clean install. Deleting these made python automatically use the correct packages.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, because I'm using PyCharm and PyCharm create a 'venv' for every project in project folder, but it is only a mini env of python. Although you have installed the libraries you need in Python, but in your custom project 'venv', it is not available. This is the real reason of 'ImportError: No module named xxxxxx' occurred in PyCharm.
To resolve this issue, you must add libraries to your project custom env by these steps:

- In PyCharm, from menu 'File'->Settings
- In Settings dialog, Project: XXXProject->Project Interpreter
- Click "Add" button, it will show you 'Available Packages' dialog
- Search your library, click 'Install Package'
- Then, all you needed package will be installed in you project custom 'venv' folder.

[image: Settings dialog]

Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

Linux: Imported modules are located in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

If you're using a module compiled in C, don't forget to chmod the .so file after `sudo setup.py install`.

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/*.so
```

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I added the directory with the `__init__.py` file to PYTHONPATH, when actually I needed to add its parent directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a setup script/utility (e.g. [setuptools](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#setuptools)) to deploy your package, don't forget to add the respective files/modules to the installer.

---

When supported, use `find_packages()` or similar to automatically add new packages to the setup script. This will absolutely save you from a headache, *especially* if you put your project aside for some time and then add something later on.

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="example-pkg",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Example Author",
    author_email="author@example.com",
    description="A small example package",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

*(Example taken from [setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html))*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (Python 2.7 Linux), I have found the solution and i would like to share it.  In my case i had the structure below:

```
Booklet
-> __init__.py
-> Booklet.py
-> Question.py
default
-> __init_.py
-> main.py
```

In 'main.py' I had tried unsuccessfully all the combinations bellow:

```
from Booklet import Question
from Question import Question
from Booklet.Question import Question
from Booklet.Question import *
import Booklet.Question
# and many othet various combinations ...
```

The solution was much more simple than I thought. I renamed the folder "Booklet" into "booklet" and that's it. Now Python can import the class Question normally by using in 'main.py' the code:

```
from booklet.Booklet import Booklet
from booklet.Question import Question
from booklet.Question import AnotherClass
```

From this I can conclude that Package-Names (folders) like 'booklet' must start from lower-case, else Python confuses it with Class names and Filenames.

Apparently, this was not your problem, but *John Fouhy's* answer is very good and this thread has almost anything that can cause this issue. So, this is one more thing and I hope that maybe this could help others.

Answer (score 1):

In linux server try `dos2unix script_name`

(remove all (if there is any) `pyc` files with command `find . -name '*.pyc' -delete`)

and re run in the case if you worked on script on windows

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using `sys.path.insert()` to import a local module and was getting `module not found` from a different library. I had to put `sys.path.insert()` below the imports that reported `module not found`. I guess the best practice is to put `sys.path.insert()` at the bottom of your imports.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that changing the name (via GUI) of aliased folders (Mac) can cause issues with loading modules. If the original folder name is changed, remake the symbolic link. I'm unsure how prevalent this behavior may be, but it was frustrating to debug.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a tight deadline and all else fails:

```
import sys
import os
wd = '/path/to/current/script/'
sys.path.append(wd)
os.chdir(wd)
print(os.getcwd())
print(sys.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

After just suffering the same issue I found my resolution was to delete all `pyc` files from my project, it seems like these cached files were somehow causing this error.

Easiest way I found to do this was to navigate to my project folder in Windows explorer and searching for `*.pyc`, then selecting all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and deleting them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).

Its possible I could have resolved my issues by just deleting the specific `pyc` file but I never tried this

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem: `Import error`. In addition the library've been installed 100% correctly. The source of the problem was that on my PC 3 version of python (anaconda packet) have been installed). This is why the library was installed no to the right place. After that I just changed to the proper version of python in the my IDE PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. It was caused by somebody creating a folder in the same folder as my script, the name of which conflicted with a module I was importing from elsewhere. Instead of importing the external module, it looked inside this folder which obviously didn't contain the expected modules.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was including the path to package.egg folder rather than the actual package underneath. I copied the package to top level and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Created `__init__.py` file inside parent folder (in your case, inside `site-packages` folder). And imported like this:

```
from site-packages.toolkit.interface import interface
```

Hope it will be useful for you as well !

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I created a new virtual environment named `python3.6`.

```sh
conda create -n python3.6 python=3.6
pip install pandas
```

everything is ok, but when I run script, a error occurred

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I found that the metadata of the Python package and cache of pip has been updated, but it does not actually download the `pandas` package.
so I try reinstall by pip,

```sh
pip uninstall pandas --no-cache-dir
pip install pandas
```

This solved it.

Answer (score 0):

In the ubuntu `apt-get` installer, the python3 versions of packages are usually named

```
python3-XYZ
```

and the python2 versions

```
python-XYZ
```

As a rule of thumb, try `python3-XYZ` or `python-XYZ` of the package that is mentioned in the error message.
And just guessing is not needed, search through the apt cache with a RegEx. Then:

```bash
$ apt-cache search "python.*toolkit.*interface"
python3-cli-helpers - easy command-line apps with Python
python3-exam - Python module to help write better tests
python3-fltk - Python wrapper for the Fast Light Toolkit
python3-mpltoolkits.basemap - matplotlib toolkit to plot on map projections (Python 3)
python3-nltk - Python3 libraries for natural language processing
python3-onnx - Open Neural Network Exchange (ONNX) (Python)
python3-paraview - Parallel Visualization Application. python-support
python3-pyswarms - research toolkit for particle swarm optimization in Python
python3-wxgtk-media4.0 - Python 3 interface to the wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (wx.media)
python3-wxgtk-webview4.0 - Python 3 interface to the wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (wx.html2)
python3-wxgtk4.0 - Python 3 interface to the wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit
python3-xapian - Xapian search engine interface for Python3
wxglade - GUI designer written in Python with wxPython
```

It does not find it.

Mind that this `apt-get` trick will sometimes be needed for dependent packages as well or instead.

I had the same error message for the flask package for python2.7 and it vanished when I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install python-flask
```

Thus, try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-[YOURPYTHONVERION]-[YOURERRORPACKAGE]
```

or check mentioned dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Using sys.path.append worked for me, as mentioned in an answer already. At first I thought it was not working until I realized I had a space before the directory path. So be sure you have no typos or spaces before you path(s)

Answer (score 0):

The file encoding of all your python files must be utf-8.

See here: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3166#issuecomment-581332097

Answer (score 0):

## another cause makes this issue

`file.py`

```py
#!/bin/python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

- if your default `python` is `pyyhon2`

```bash
$ file $(which python)
/sbin/python: symbolic link to python2
```

- `file.py` need `python3`, for this case(`bs4`)
- you can not execute this module with `python2` like this:

```bash
$ python file.py
# or
$ file.py
# or
$ file.py # if locate in $PATH
```

- Tow way to fix this `error`,

```bash
# should be to make python3 as default by symlink
$ rm $(which python) && ln -s $(which python3) /usr/bin/python
# or use alias
alias python='/usr/bin.../python3'
```

or change `shebang` in `file.py` to

```bash
#!/usr/bin/...python3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. In my case, the following thing happened:

I had a self-made package installed, and it had `toolkit` directory in it. Therefore, when Python looked for `interface` module, it searched for it not in the directory on `sys.path`, but in the directory of preinstalled package.

Having uninstalled this package via `pip`, everything got fixed for me.