# Python : Having issue to Import a function from a file in a different folder

Tags: python, import, directory

in my python project, I have 2 folders:

```
folder_A
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
    c.py

folder_B
    __init__.py
    main.py
```

With in main.py, I am using this command:

```
from folder_A.a import function1
```

When running the program I get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'folder_A'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `main.py` located?

Comment: main.py is in folder_B. Look in my explanation : folder_A & folder_B

Comment: Possibl duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476682/fail-python-import-from-another-folder

Comment: Is the folder that `folder_A` and `folder_B` are contained in on `sys.path`?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 3):

Upon execution, the current folder is added to the python path. However if you are executing

```
~/myproject/$ python folder_B/main.py
```

Then the current path resolves inside `folder_B`, so folder_A is not in the python path.

You can execute the main module from the upper project folder:

```
~/myproject/$ python -m folder_B.main
```

Otherwise, you can set the PYTHONPATH env var

```
~/myproject/folder_B/$ PYTHONPATH=".." python main.py
```