# Video streaming using Python+openCV through Client and Server

Tags: python, opencv, client-server, client

I made a small Server Client Video streaming program in Python. I used "VideoCapture" module for getting the image frames in Windows. But actually i wanted to do the project in Raspberry Pi. Then i asked Google, and of course, some of the friends from Stackoverfow told that openCV in python is an option. I installed openCV on Windows. After that i made a simple program from the samples given by the openCV installation files. I found a sample called "camshift" and from that i made a simple webcam viewer. But got an error "No module named video"for my program and at the same time "camshift" program is working without any error. Both programs are using the module "video". Please help to solve this problem and also help me to send these captured images to the client. Thank you in advance.

> **My Webcam viewer program**

```
import cv2
import video
import sys
cam=video.create_capture(0)
while 1:
    flag, frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('camera', frame)
    ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1)
    if ch==10:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be an error that occur sometimes when you edit your  `__init__.py` file on windows (take a look at  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-importerror-no-module-named) and see if that is the case).

Comment: But i am using openCV. There in no directory like "../Lib/site-packages/". But inside the openCV folder there is a module folder and inside that i didn't find any __init__.py files. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The "video" module is imported from openCV, not from Python.