# Force pip to install in system site-packages?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-16.04

When I install packages with python 3 on ubuntu 16.04, they get installed to my local user ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages.  How do I force pip to install to the system-wide site packages?

I'm trying by using `pip3 install <pkg>`

Thanks.

This is NOT a duplicate of [How to make my Python module available system wide on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236675/how-to-make-my-python-module-available-system-wide-on-linux) - because that is about creating your own module, not a a strange way that pip is working for a Pypi module.  Not even close, actually, other than they both deal with modules.

Comment: i guess you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236675/how-to-make-my-python-module-available-system-wide-on-linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make my Python module available system wide on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236675/how-to-make-my-python-module-available-system-wide-on-linux)

Comment: @ShubhamNamdeo - nope.  that's for creating your own modules.  This is for a module from pip.

Comment: The Ubuntu people don't want you to do that, because the system-wide package set is normally managed by APT rather than Pip.  Why do you want to do that, and why can't you use a virtualenv?

Comment: @Kevin - mostly - no exp using virtual env on linux.

Comment: Some useful information missing from the question: what command are you running?

Comment: If you want to install to the system you probably want `sudo pip3 install ...` instead of `pip3 install ...`