# ImportError: No Module Named <parent dir>

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, directory, code-reuse

I am trying to learn programming through Python, so I apologize in advance if this is an absurdly simple question.

I am attempting to simplify my convoluted directory structure and utilize some of Python's code-reuse features, I have encountered what is for me an inexplicable `ImportError` error.  For the past several hours I've been reading about Python's `import`, `module`, and `package` features ([here](http://goo.gl/GvnxsO), [here](http://goo.gl/owxN1W), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-importerror-no-module-named), and [here](http://goo.gl/Ke9lBk) among others), yet I remain unable to solve this (seemingly) simple error.

Here is the problem.

I have one directory (`dir`), within which resides one sub-directory (`subdir`).  Each directory includes a few files.  Thus, my overall directory structure looks like the following:

```
dir/
    __init__.py
    draw_lib.py
    subdir/
        __init___.py
        drawing.py
```

In my `drawing.py` file, I attempt to import `draw_lib.py` with the following line: `from dir import daw_lib.py`. It results in an `ImportError: No module named dir`. Can anyone provide a quick explanation for why my `drawing.py` file can't find my `dir` directory? Thank you for any assistance.  I'm completely lost and would really like to improve my code reuse and directory structure once and for all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are initially executing **draw_lib.py**. So the 'root directory' is **/** throughout the program.

Then, when you attempt '*from dir import draw_lib.py*' in **drawing.py** it wont work because the root directory is still **/** and not **dir/**.

```
import draw_lib
```

Will work in **drawing.py**.

### Example:

```
/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    test/
        __init___.py
        case.py
```

In **main.py**, put this:

```
import test.case

print 'main.py'

if __name__ == "__main__":
        test.case.test()
```

In **test/case.py**, put this:

```
import main

def test():
        print 'case.py'
```

My output:

```
main.py
main.py
case.py
```

As you can see, I imported **main.py** from a nested file. You'll see **main.py** two times. Once for the initial startup the second time when you import it in **case.py**.

Comment: tried it.  when I import `draw_lib`, I get the same error: `ImportError: No module named draw_lib`.  Would that it were so simply :)

Comment: Works here. I added an example to my answer :)

Comment: it doesn't work for me.  I followed it word for word.  any recommendations?  could it be a screwy `PythonPath`? (either way, thanks for all of your help.  these inexplicable, hours-long, seemingly-simple errors can be disheartening so, as someone who's just learning, I really appreciate the SO and other python communities.)

Comment: How are you executing the script? Are you in the same directory as main.py? What OS is this on? And don't worry, we've all been trough the programming hours where everything seems to fail.

Comment: Windows OS.  I am executing the script from the command line in the `test/` directory.

Comment: You should be in the root directory. Then do 'python main.py'.

Comment: okay, brilliant.  it works when I do that, but can one only ever import from subdirectories -- i.e., down the directory tree -- or is there a way to do what I was attempting to do?  also, thanks a million for your help.  I will accept your answer.

Comment: No, there is no way to do what you originally wanted to do. From a design perspective there is no point in doing that.

The only 2 ways to import a 'foreign' module is if its locatable within the root directory OR if it is installed as a module into Python's module directory (/usr/lib/python2.7/). I've never had to import the 'main' Python file from a second, nested Python file. It complicates things. Your 'main' should import modules and use them, not the other way around :)

Answer (score -1):

for reference please refer to this link,
https://askubuntu.com/a/1163934/1748542

just add the lines of code mentioned in the linked answer to the root `main.py` or `xyz.py` or any such file.
It should work like charm

eg:

```
parentdir
  |
  __init__.py
  main.py
  |
  subdir
    |
    __init__.py
    a.py
```

**main.py**

```py
import os, sys

#Following lines are for assigning parent directory dynamically.

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

parent_dir_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir_path, os.pardir))

sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir_path)

from parentdir.subdir import a
```

Done your error is resolved

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)