# ImportError: No module named setuptools, windows

Tags: python

I'm installing the [mwlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mwlib/0.15.14) `python library` on `windows`, I used `setup.py install`, and have set the `environment variable` for python, some `similar` answer about `__init__.py` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-importerror-no-module-named) doesn't solve my problem, how should I solve this? I'm new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you haven't installed [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads) yet, install this library first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not installed setuptools.

Taken from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools):

> The recommended way to bootstrap setuptools on any system is to
>   download [ez_setup.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py) and run it using the target Python
>   environment. Different operating systems have different recommended
>   techniques to accomplish this basic routine, so below are some
>   examples to get you started.