# ImportError: No module named

Tags: python

I encountered this error when I tried to run my project. Line of code producing this error is:

```
from DomainServices.models.movie import Movie
```

But I have Movle class in my model folder and movie.py file. I also have an `__init__.py` containing:

```
__author__ = 'ehsan'
```

As I've read here: [Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-importerror-no-module-named) I'm sure the problem is not about **init**.py contents, because I replaced this file with a working one from another project.
Whole error is:

```
[root@h149-3-137-195 DomainServices]$ python DomainServices/cron/imdb_crawler.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DomainServices/cron/imdb_crawler.py", line 6, in <module>
    from DomainServices.models.movie import Movie
ImportError: No module named DomainServices.models.movie
```

This is my project structure:
[image: ImportError: No module named]

In the project directory when I run 'python' and run that import command, there is no problem!
What should I do?

Comment: What's your `PYTHONPATH`? You may need to add `.` into it (as well as an empty `__init__.py` inside `DomainServices/DomainServices`, as @ThiefMaster pointed out in their answer).

Comment: @JamesAylett In the project directory when I run 'python' and run that import command, there is no problem!

Comment: If your project structure above is up to date then you still don't have an `__init__.py` in the `DomainServices` directory, which is needed to make `DomainServices` a module.

Answer (score 6):

You should make `DomainServices` a package by creating a `__init__.py` in there and then use absolute imports:

```
from DomainServices.models.movie import Movie
```

Comment: I copied __init__.py in DomainServices. but the problem persists and I can not use absolute address because DomainServices is not a known name in my files! what to do?

Comment: Then put some other folder inside DomainServices. Your application really needs a top-level package!

Comment: Problem persists! I did what you told and updated my question with my news project structure. what should I do?

Comment: In the project directory when I run 'python' and run that import command, there is no problem!