# Issue in importing vincent in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, installation, vincent

i have installed vincent-o.1.6 "python setup.py install" and it has created "vincent-0.1.6-py2.7.egg" this file in my "site-packages" folder but when i import it in my program using "import vincent" it throws the following error 
"import vincent
ImportError: No module named vincent"

Need some help please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python ImportError No module named](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-importerror-no-module-named)

Comment: My question is different and simple