# ImportError: no module named _CRFPP in Python 2.7.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, swig, crf

I installed CRF++0.58 in Python 2.7.6

When I try to import I have the following message:

```
    >>> import CRFPP
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "CRFPP.py", line 42, in <module>
        _CRFPP = swig_import_helper()
      File "CRFPP.py", line 34, in swig_import_helper
        import _CRFPP
    ImportError: No module named _CRFPP
    >>>
```

The procedure to install is described in the README file in python directory of CRF++0.58, and is:

```
  $ python setup.py build
  $ sudo python setup.py install
```

This placed in the directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ :

1. CRFPP.py
2. CRFPP.pyc
3. _CRFPP.so

   The directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ is in the sys.path

   In the CRFPP.py in the setup directory contains, in its begin, the following procedure:

   ```
   #This file was automatically generated by SWIG (http://www.swig.org).
   # Version 2.0.4
   #
   # Do not make changes to this file unless you know what you are doing--modify
   # the SWIG interface file instead.

   from sys import version_info
   if version_info >= (2,6,0):
       def swig_import_helper():
           from os.path import dirname
           import imp
           fp = None
           try:
               fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_CRFPP',[dirname(__file__)])
           except ImportError:
               import _CRFPP
               return _CRFPP
           if fp is not None:
               try:
                   _mod = imp.load_module('_CRFPP', fp, pathname, description)
               finally:
                   fp.close()
               return _mod
       _CRFPP = swig_import_helper()
       del swig_import_helper
   else:
       import _CRFPP
   del version_info
   ```

imp does not find _CRFPP.so, but found CRFPP.py:

```
    >>> import imp
    >>> imp.find_module("_CRFPP")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named _CRFPP

    >>> imp.find_module("CRFPP")
    (<open file '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CRFPP.py', mode 'U' at 0x7f7748e4a540>, '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CRFPP.py', ('.py', 'U', 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in:

[Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-importerror-no-module-named?rq=1)

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23964457/5283795

posted in May 30 '14 at 22:50 by KrisWebDev :

sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/*.so

After this I imported the module.

Initially the module was with the following attributes:

-rwxrwx---  1 root staff 255671 Jul 22  2014 _CRFPP.so

After the command:

-rwxr-xr-x  1 root staff 255671 Jul 22  2014 _CRFPP.so