# Can't import UTC from icalendar

Tags: python, timezone, icalendar

I tried to run an old script which contains the following line:

```
from icalendar import UTC
```

This gave me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name UTC
```

So I checked out the change log of `icalendar` which states the following:

> Renamed the `UTC` class to `Utc`, so it would not clash with the `UTC` object, since that rendered the `UTC` object unpicklable.

I changed `UTC` into `Utc` and still get the same error.

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **timezone support** section of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/icalendar, it states that:

> Instead of our own UTC tzinfo implementation we use pytz UTC tzinfo
>   object now.

I would therefore suggest that you use:

```
from pytz import UTC
```

...instead of:

```
from icalendar import UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

Python don't see your local directory:

1. Check it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/339220/3260314
2. Check your sys.path

   import sys.path
   print sys.path

If this hasn't your directory:

```
sys,path.insert(1, path)
```