# sklearn.learning_curve issue (python)?

Tags: scikit-learn

Problem with scikit learn: I can't use `learning_curve` of sklearn.

When I do: `import sklearn` (it works), `from sklearn.cluster import bicluster` (it works), `from sklearn import cross_validation` (it works)... and so on. The only file that doesn't work is `learning_curve`,namely `from sklearn.learning_curve import learning_curve` (doesn't work).

Two types of error to consider:

1. `from sklearn import learning_curve`

   > Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  ImportError: cannot import name learning_curve
2. `from sklearn.learning_curve import learning_curve`

   > Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  ImportError: No module named learning_curve

Any clue?

Comment: Perhaps this might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-importerror-no-module-named (In my installation of Anaconda, the import works fine.)

Comment: thanks yes it helps me

Comment: @vincet how finally it worked for you, could you please also post solution, I'm facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

the learning_curve in scikit learn is under model_selection
So try,

```
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
```

This works fine!

Answer (score 0):

```py
# will work 
from sklearn.model_selection import validation_curve

# won't work 
from sklearn.learning_curve import validation_curve
```