# No module named 'urls.py'

Tags: django

I am new to the environment of django and I am trying to create an url link; however, the error reads

```
ImportError: No module named 'myprofile'
```

Therefore I am stuck here asking the question of how to fix this problem. I have looked over several forum; however, I couldn't come across the solution to this particular problem. Thank You for helping.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^myprofile$',include("myprofile.urls"), name = myprofile)
]
```

Comment: I tried but the error still stands

Comment: Do you have a myprofile directory? Does it have a urls.py? Where is it in relation to this file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an app called `myprofile` which includes a `views.py` you should form your URL like the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include
from myprofile import views as myprofileViews

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^myprofile$', myprofileViews.SomeViewName)
]
```

You should then have to have the following code in `myprofile/views.py`:

```
def SomeViewName(request):
   return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be that you're missing __init__.py in the myprofile app. This is a file in the directory of the app, and it's enough if it's empty. This file will make python recognize the directory as a module.

Also see this question:
[Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-importerror-no-module-named)