# Module already installed but "ImportError"

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, anaconda

I have installed the modules (for example: configobj, matplotlib, etc.) but when I try to import these modules in my Python script and try to run those scripts using Linux/Ubuntu 14 command prompt, it is giving "ImportError: No module named configobj".
But if I try to import the same module using ipython, it is not giving any issue.
Python version: 2.7.6 (when I checked with sys.version in ipython)

I have already installed anaconda. I don't know whether it can trigger any issues.

Tried:
[Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-importerror-no-module-named)

I have tried changing $PYTHONPATH to point to anaconda lib/ directory as it was suggested in some post on stackoverflow only. Also, checked many questions here but unable to find any solution.

Followed some other links as well.

Thanks :)

Comment: When you run 'pip freeze' do you have your modules in the list?

Comment: File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Comment: Could you try this procedure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources and reinstall your package after

Comment: I don't have that much knowledge with Python packages. This link thing is not working for me . Instead I tried reinstalling it using :sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pkg-resources but now, I am not even able to use ipython (maybe because of some interconnection with pkg_tools)

Comment: It's helpful if you described how you installed Python, and IPython on this setup. The fact that module loads in IPython but the Python script can not load it, shows that the module is installed somewhere, that is not available in your Python interpreter PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Your new module needs to be in a path like

```
C:\Users\**SOMEUSER**\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages
```

then you should install the module from cmd with

```
python setup.py install
```

(dont forget to cd to the modules directory in cmd..)

as there should be a "setup.py"-file in the modules directory.

You do not need your env-variable to look into Anaconda2\lib, who did you tell this?!

PYTHONPATH is for your python.exe to call python from cmd...

Comment: Are you giving this path according to the windows ? there is no site-packages in anaconda/lib/ in my Ubuntu structure

Comment: Yes, this one is for Windows....search the equivalent for  "site-packages" in Ubuntu and dont forget to **python setup.py install**