# How to Import module or a file from subfolder in Python?

Tags: python

Have a file `test.py`, located on a Directory for eg `/pyproject`. and in `/pyproject` have a subdirectory called `api` which have two subdirectorys called `gmail` and `facebook` and in both directory have `.py` file such as :

```
/pyproject/api/gmail/abc.py
/pyproject/api/facebook/xyz.py
```

Have import abc and xyz py file  from test.py:

```
import api.gmail.abc
```

Which resulted:

```
  File "./test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import api.gmail.abc
ImportError: No module named api.gmail.abc
```

is There any ideas how to import xyz/abc from subdirectory to main `test.py` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Doing some R&D, Have done it 
Just need to create `__init__.py` (a empty py file) and add it to all subdirectory
such as

```
 /pyproject/
    api/
      __init__.py
      gmail/
          __init__.py
          abc.py

      facebook/
         __init__.py
         xyz.py
```

And add in main py file

```
from api.gmail.abc import *
or
import api.gmail.abc
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an empty `__init__.py` file in each directory, it's a marker that tells python this folder is a module. I think it should solve the problem for python2.

In python3 imports have been slightly changed, and there you'll also need to use `-m` command line parameter.

If the file you're trying to run is for example `.../pyproject/src/scraper.py`
You need to set your working directory to the project root `.../pyproject/`, and run:

`python -m src.scraper`

In this example I used a longer path to show that sub-directories are delimited by a `.` instead of `/`. In your case `python -m test` should work fine.