# Windows - Pycharm - Failed to install python packaging tools

Tags: python, pycharm

In trying to install packages in Pycharm for the Python 3.6 interpreter, I get

```
Python packaging tools not found. *Install packaging tools*
```

And when I tried to install it gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 
2017.3.1\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 2, in <module>
    import traceback
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'traceback'
```

I'm using Pycharm 2017.3.1 Community Edition

Comment: Check your environement variables for your PATH configuration. For Windows it's somewhere under Advanced System Settings > Environment Varibles > System Varibles. See this page it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `pycharm`,

goto `settings` -> `project Interpreter`

Click on `+` button on top right corner and you will get pop-up window of Available packages. Then search for `packaging` python package.

Then click on Install package to install the package.

Comment: I'm late for the party, but I'm having the same issue. Somehow everything goes wrong when I installed a new virtual env to view the source code of tablib, which requires a bunch of libraries installed. Then suddenly my other venvs got messed up. pip3.exe is in the directory, but PyCharm insists that it is not there, and when I tried to install a new one, SRE module mismatch occured. The whole thing made me think that Python development environment is still not as mature as, say, VS. It is difficult to go wrong in VS from my exp.

Comment: Because it does not have packaging tools, the `+` button is disabled for me. Can't install anything.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. In the end I had to remove an existing venv that was in the same location, delete multiple interpreters, then set up a new one.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth..
I had a similar problem. Nothing answered here worked for me.
The problem started with Pycharm upgrade. The solution was to uninstall Pycharm, and  obliterate what's in the Configuration directory (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory) along with alll jetbrains directories.

Reinstalled Phycharm 2022.1.1. Viola. Alas I have to reinstall all plugins I used in the old installation.

As far as I can tell, the problem - in my case at least - was the upgrade process.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer wouldn't directly work if you have already created a Virtual environment.
That virtual environment would not be usable. So, go ahead and delete it.

Then, go and install the `packaging` module in the base python version, as shown in the accepted answer and then create a new virtual environment.

That new virtual environment can now be used.