# ImportError: No module... After python setup.py install

Tags: python, installation, python-import, setuptools, importerror

I'm having trouble installing one of my python scripts. It has the following structure:

```
myproject
  setup.py
  src
    myproject
      otherfolders
      main.py
      __init__.py
```

And my `setup.py`creates an entry point like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='mypackage',
version='2.4.0',
author='me',
author_email='...',
package_dir={'':'src'},
packages=find_packages('myproject'),
install_requires=[
    "networkx",
    "geopy",
    "pyyaml"
],
zip_safe=False,
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'myproject=myproject.main:main',
    ],
},
)
```

Now, after installing this successfully with `sudo python setup.py install`, I run `mypackage` and get an import error: `No module named mypackage.main`.

I am aware that there are lots of similar questions and I tried most/all solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named), e.g., checking the `__init__.py` and setting `PYTHONPATH`, but the problem still exists.
I'm running this on two different Ubuntu 16.04 machines.

I'm pretty sure this worked before, but even when I go back to an earlier commit it doesn't work now.

I noticed the installation works with `develop` but still fails with `install`. Does that make sense to anyone?

Comment: Which Python version are you targeting?  Currently it's 2.7

Comment: The script is written in Python 3.5. I also tried installing it with `sudo python3 setup.py install` (also successful), but when I run it, I get a similar error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject`

Comment: python setup.py stuff is the worst thing about python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was in [`find_packages()`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages):

> Some projects use a src or lib directory as the root of their source tree, and those projects would of course use "src" or "lib" as the first argument to `find_packages()`.

Hence, I had to change `find_packages('myproject')` to `find_packages('src')`.

Comment: It's not very clear, can you add some tree structure please ?

Comment: The tree structure of files is at the top in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`packages=find_packages('mypackage')` -> `packages=find_packages('myproject')`.

Also you should use `myproject.main`.

Comment: You're right. But that was just a typo when copying it to stackoverflow. It's correct in my git. I edited the question