# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <modulename> after installing custom package with pip

Tags: python, pip

Before asking this question, I have seen the following questions that are somehow similar to my question, but they didn't resolve the existing error:

- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named  after pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305504/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-modulename-after-pip-install)
- [ImportError: No module… After python setup.py install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295992/importerror-no-module-after-python-setup-py-install)

I have the following structure:

```sh
backbone-project
├── backbone
│   ├── backbone.py
│   ├── cmd_parser.py
│   ├── command_executor.py
│   ├── config_files
│   ├── db_connections
│   ├── extras
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── query_files
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests
│   └── utils
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
```

and this is my *setup.py* file:

```py
import setuptools
from backbone.utils.enums import Files, Letters


with open(Files.README.value, Letters.R.value, encoding=Letters.UTF_8.value) as readme_file:
    long_description = readme_file.read()

with open(Files.REQUIREMENTS.value, Letters.R.value, encoding=Letters.UTF_8.value) as requirements_file:
    requirements = requirements_file.read().splitlines()

setuptools.setup(
    name="backbone",
    version="1",
    entry_points={
      "console_scripts": [
          'backbone=backbone.backbone:main'
      ]
    },
    author="Mostafa Ghadimi",
    author_email="my email",
    long_description=long_description,
    install_requirements=requirements,
    # install_requires=requirements,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="url",
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    package_dir={"": "backbone"},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages("backbone"),
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    license='MIT',
)
```

**backbone/backbone.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from cmd_parser import parse_args
from utils.logger import Logger
from utils.enums import Messages


def main():
    logger = Logger(__name__)
    logger.log(Messages.BACKBONE_WELCOME_MSG.value)
    parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is that whenever I want to install the package, it is installed successfully, but as the command is being executed, the error is raised:

requirements.txt

```
git+https://<username>:<password>@<git_repository_url>.git
```

and install it using the following command:

```
pip install -r requirements
```

(It has been installed without any error.)

As I want to use the package (in bash), I face to following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/bin/backbone", line 5, in <module>
    from backbone import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'backbone' (unknown location)
```

How can I resolve this error?

**P.S. 1** On local after exporting `PYTHONPATH` the problem is resolved, but the problem still exists when I want to install the package from git repository!

**P.S. 2** I am somehow sure that the problem is with `entry_points`. I have also tried `backbone:main` but it doesn't work!

Comment: I spot lots of strange things... But first of all, I think you don't need the `package_dir` line in your `setup.py`. Then it should be `install_requires=...` (and not `install_requirements`).

Comment: @sinoroc would you mind helping me resolving the existing problem?

Comment: I don't know. Too many things seems wrong. Maybe try this: In your `requirements.txt` you should write something like `backbone @ git+https://...`.

Comment: @sinoroc I have tried this one and it doesn't work. I am somehow sure that the problem is with `entry_points`, but I don't know how to resolve it. I will add my backbone.py file in a minute.

Comment: In you entry points you mention `backbone.main:main`, but you do not seem to have any `backbone.main` module (or package), in other words there is no `backbone/main.py` (or `backbone/main/__init__.py`).

Comment: @sinoroc I have also tried backbone.backbone.main:main but it doesn’t work. Is it possible for you to give me upvote?

Comment: But what do you want your entry point function to actually be? What is the name of the function? In which module/package is it? In which file? You don't seem to have any `main` file or directory, so it has to be something else.

Comment: @sinoroc I will try backbone.backbone:main is that ok?

Comment: I don't know. Where is your function? You did not answer. What is the name of the function? In which file is the function? If you have a function `main` in the file `backbone/backone.py` then `backbone.backbone:main` should work.

Comment: @sinoroc I haved applied the change (`backbone.backbone:main`), now still have another error (I have updated the post). Would you please take a look at it?

Comment: The error message does not seem to match what your project structure is claimed to be. If the entry point is `backbone.backbone:main`, then I would expect the error message to be `cannot import name 'main' from 'backbone.backbone'`. -- It is hard to follow what the real project structure is, I am confused. -- Maybe you should make 100% sure to uninstall this `backbone` application properly, then reinstall. -- If you are familiar with Python virtual environments, you could experiment in one.

Comment: @sinoroc yes I'm not beginner with Python and its applications. I've done the thing you've said in the main function of backbone/backbone.py I call another  function called parse_args and I have applied the changes you've said. It doesn't work. Would you please give me more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that there already exist package named 'backbone'. So it installs it from pip. But what you need is local module, which is also called 'backbone'. To fix this, simple type '.backbone' (add dot before the module name) instead of 'backbone'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would you please mention were should I apply the changes? Would you mind editing the answer?

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi The changes should be in the top of setup.py file, where you import 'main' from 'backbone'. Moreover, I suggest removing the module that you installed so it doesn't conflict.

Comment: It's not fixed using `.backbone` for local command. is there any way to name it as backbone except alias?