# python import sybpydb ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python

I am scratching my hairs and trying to find out why I am always having such error.

1. I have sybpydb installed on my laptop (win 7 professional) in c drive: `C:\FAST\anaconda\python27\win64\431\Lib\site-packages\`, as per below:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxh2u.jpg)
2. I had set the path to that location: `C:\FAST\anaconda\python27\win64\431\Lib\site-packages\`, as per below:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PQve.jpg)

But whenever I try to `import sybpydb`, i am always getting this error message:

```
>>> import sybpydb

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sybpydb`
```

I was googling and treid the suggested steps:-

1. https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SYBCON/Debugging+Error+messages+with+python+samples
2. [Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named)) but no avail, would anyone has come across this before please?

Comment: How did you install the library?

Comment: thanks mate, but which library are you referring? the sybpydb? i installed Anaconda for Pythong 2.x, and Python Plugin for IntelliJ, it must be installed alone either of those 2 installation.