# Neo Smart Contract boa.blockchain module

Tags: python

i want to build a smart contract with neo-python and in my sc i want to have this module:

```
from boa.blockchain.vm.Neo.Storage import GetContext, Get, Put, Delete
```

but i get
`No module named boa.blockchain`
How can i get this module linked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to put `from`, and also did you install it with `pip install neo-boa` ?

```
from boa.blockchain.vm.Neo.Storage import GetContext, Get, Put, Delete
```

Comment: oh yeah, but not in my python-SC. I just forgot to copy the `from`

Comment: did you install it ? do you have folder or files `boa.blockchain` ?

Comment: i installed `neo-boa` via `pip install neo-boa` in my `venv` for neo-python. But i it still doesn't compile. I don't know what i need here....