# Python 3 html module import error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I am using python 3.5....One of the dependency file I am using has this line

```
import html
```

The file is also coded in python.
So I get this error:

> import html ImportError: No module named html

So I tried

> sudo apt-get install html

And it gives me this error

> E: Unable to locate package html

Comment: I get error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-rhy16f8i/html/
When I tried pip3 install html

Comment: The html module is part of the standard library, you shouldn't need to install it separately and this may be indicative of a problem with the python installation on this system.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3.5?  That version has [an `html` module built in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html).  You might actually be using Python 2, which does not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install html module try this:

```
pip install html
```

To import html module in python :

```
from html import HTML
h = HTML()
```

For better understanding here is an example :

```
h.p('Hello, world!')
print h
```

I hope it works.

Comment: [html](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/html.html) is already part of standard library

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you run .py scripts for version 3 with the python.exe version 2.   I my case, running python from any directory would always start up version 3, however, windows file associations for .py extension were made for the older python directory.