# Why xlsxwriter module does not work like other modules?

Tags: python-2.7, xlsxwriter

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:TC.py", line 1, in <module>
    import xlsxwriter
ImportError: No module named xlsxwriter
```

I am getting this error even after trying every possible answer given to this problem earlier.

I am using python 2.7 in windows
I have installed xlsxwriter using pip

I have tried reinstalling python shell but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named)

Comment: You have to install first since it is not a builtin. `pip install xlsxwriter`

Comment: The answer has been answered earlier, but all those steps doesn't work for me

Comment: Maybe you have other python version

Comment: Try `python -m pip install xlsxwriter` and run `python TC.py`

Comment: It gives the following statement:

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: xlsxwriter in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter-1.1.8-py2.7.egg (1.1.8)

Comment: How you run the file

Comment: I open the file in python shell and then run it using F5

Comment: What do you get for `import sys ; print(sys.version)`

Comment: 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:37:19) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]