# Unable to find installed python packages on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror, paramiko

I'm running python code which is dependent on the external package paramiko. I've installed this package and also added the the path where it was installed to the PYTHONPATH. Still the code is not able to import the package.

I get the error:
ImportError: No module named paramiko

Below is my environment and script I'm trying to run. Any suggestions to fix this issue will be highly appreciated

(helper_scripts) is the virtual environment.

```
  (helper_scripts) kapss-mbp:helper_scripts kap$ sudo 
  ./create_fyre_cluster.py kap --cluster=KapilCluster --icp-base --docker-raw-disk --key=abc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./create_fyre_cluster.py", line 9, in <module>
    import paramiko
ImportError: No module named paramiko

(helper_scripts) kapss-mbp:helper_scripts kap$ which python
/Users/kap/.virtualenvs/helper_scripts/bin/python

(helper_scripts) kapss-mbp:helper_scripts kap$ python -V
Python 3.7.3


echo  $PYTHONPATH
:/Users/kap/.virtualenvs/helper_scripts/lib/python3.7/site-packages


kapss-mbp:site-packages kap$ cd /Users/kap/.virtualenvs/helper_scripts/lib/python3.7/site-packages


kapss-mbp:site-packages kap$ ls PyNaCl-1.3.0.dist-info          cryptography                pycparser
__pycache__             cryptography-2.7.dist-info      pycparser-2.19.dist-info
_cffi_backend.cpython-37m-darwin.so easy-install.pth            requests-2.22.0-py3.7.egg asn1crypto                easy_install.py             setuptools asn1crypto-0.24.0.dist-info      idna-2.8-py3.7.egg          setuptools-41.2.0.dist-info bcrypt                  nacl                    six-1.12.0.dist-info bcrypt-3.1.7.dist-info         paramiko                six.py certifi-2019.6.16-py3.7.egg      paramiko-2.6.0.dist-info        urllib3-1.25.3-py3.7.egg cffi                   pip                 wheel cffi-1.12.3.dist-info         pip-19.2.3.dist-info            wheel-0.33.6.dist-info chardet-3.0.4-py3.7.egg          pkg_resources
```

Comment: Is the code running in docker?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issues sometime back and this helped.. https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html

You can also have a look at this post [Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named)