# Flask - ModuleNotFoundError, though it is in the same folder - Updated

Tags: python, flask

everyone. Can't understand where my problem is.

My structure is:

[image]

But in my cmd I have:

```
(venv2) C:\Users\chainsaw\Desktop\work\bot-1\archie\autosales_bot>flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployme
nt.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "autosales_bot.wsgi", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\chainsaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-pac
kages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\chainsaw\Desktop\work\bot-1\archie\autosales_bot\__init__.py",
line 1, in <module>
    from admin_panel.run import generate_password
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'admin_panel'
```

Thanks in advance
Maybe I should run it as

```
python run.py
```

?

I have init.py in my apps

[image]

Comment: Do you have the file __init__.py inside admin_panel folder? we can't see it in that picture.

Comment: yes, i have this file

Comment: have a look at this one, editing \_\_init\_\_.py in windows sometimes is tricky.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named

Comment: thanks, should have added app path to sys.path