# How to solve cannot import name 'abort' from 'werkzeug.exceptions' error while importing Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am getting error while importing flask,
error message goes as

> ImportError: cannot import name 'abort' from 'werkzeug.exceptions'

here is my full code

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,jsonify
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pickle
app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def homepage():
    print("home")
    return render_template("Index.html")
@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    print("predict")
    preg=int(request.form["PreganciesName"])
    glucose=float(request.form["GlucoseName"])
    BP=float(request.form["BloodPressureName"])
    st=int(request.form["SkinThicknessName"])
    insu=float(request.form["InsulinName"])
    bmi=float(request.form["BMIName"])
    dpf=float(request.form["DPFName"])
    age=int(request.form["ageName"])
    print("fetching data done")
    scaler=StandardScaler()
    filename = 'Diabetis with logistic regression.pickle'
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
    print("model loded")
    a = loaded_model.predict(scaler.transform([[preg,glucose,BP,st,insu,bmi,dpf,age]]))
    print("otput "+str(a))
    return  render_template('result.html',a[0])
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess problem was with python 3.8 version. I reinstalled python 3.6 and it worked. I think it will also work fine for python 3.7

Answer (score 1):

There is no import of `abort` in the code that you posted.

However, have a look where the error is raised and replace the `abort` that you're wrongly importing with:

```
from flask import abort
```

[Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.abort)

Comment: abort is called internally when i try to import flask. I am getting error at line 1.

Comment: Then have a look at this github issue: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/issues/318 but most probably your python installation is the trouble

Comment: i have re installed python with the latest version also pycharm and also flask....in past i have built few flask app which was running perfectly in past, now when i tried to run those flask app i am getting same error which was running perfectly in past

Comment: however when i try to import flask in my jupyter notebook there is no error

Comment: have a look at your interpreter settings in pycharm then. Is that the same as jupyter?

Comment: i don't know how to check the setting for jupyter notebook

Answer (score -2):

On Linux, I had the same error message for the flask package for python2.7:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/**init**.py", line
> 17, in  from werkzeug.exceptions import abort ImportError: No
> module named werkzeug.exceptions

I could reproduce this error by running

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import abort
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
```

and the following command fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get install python-flask
```

For Python 3, it should be:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-flask
```

No need to guess, look it up with:

```sql
$ apt-cache search "python.*flask$"
python3-flask - micro web framework based on Werkzeug and Jinja2 - Python 3.x
python3-frozen-flask - Freezes a Flask application into a set of static files
python3-pylint-flask - Pylint plugin for analyzing Flask applications (Python 3)
python3-pytest-flask - pytest plugin to test Python Flask - Python 3 version
python3-typeshed - collection of library stubs for Python, with static types
```

This solution can be generalised, see [Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70311337/11154841).