# Cannot install modules inside Docker container with Jupiter notebook image

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, python-module

I have got the following Docker file

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook

COPY . ./work

RUN pip install -r ./work/requirements.txt

COPY setup.py /work

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -e .



COPY src /work/src

WORKDIR /work
```

and the following project structure:

```
almond_analysis:
    notebooks:
        data_exploration.ipynb
    src:
       __init__.py
       plots.py
    .gitignore
    docker-compose.yml
    Dockerfile
    README.md
    requirements.txt
    setup.py
```

Inside the `data_exploration.ipynb` notebook, I would like to import the module `src` with the command `import src as test`. However, despite me having typed `RUN pip install -e .` in the Dockerfile, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`. When I do to my container though, inside the `work` directory, and run `pip install -e .` the error goes away. I tried adding `CMD pip install -e .` at the end of the Dockerfile without success. I read also what was suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61518741/python-project-cant-find-modules-inside-of-docker) post (more specifically to add the lines `RUN apt-get update` and
`RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends` but without success.

My `setup.py` file looks like this:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath( os.path.dirname(__file__)))


requirements_path="requirements.txt"
with open(requirements_path) as requirements_file:
    requirements = requirements_file.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name="almond_analysis",
    version="0.0.1",
    description = "Almond analysis",
    long_description="Analysing yield with Python."
    author= "George N",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=requirements,
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3"
    ],
    python_requires =">= 3.0.*",
)
```

Does someone have an idea on how to make the `ModuleNotFoundError` go away?

Comment: Do you need to "install" `src`? From the notebook, you should already be able to do `from src import plots`. Without seeing your setup file, we don't know what the real module name should be

Comment: I have now included the `setup.py` file in the question.

Comment: Okay, so looks like you should be trying to import `almond_analysis`, not `src` since that is the name of the module, but like I said, you should also be able to import directly from the folder/package without "installing" anything else.

Comment: I cannot import directly from the folder/package right after I have typed `docker compose up` . If I go into `data_exploration.ipynb` and type `import src as test` or `from src import plots`, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`. However, if I go inside my container (inside the `work/` directory) and type `pip install -e .`, both these errors go away. I want not to have to go in the container and type `pip install -e .`, but instead for this command to be run in the `RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -e .` line in my Dockerfile.

Comment: The module you are installing is called `almond_analysis`, not `src`, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount your code under the `work` folder, then you don't need to install anything, or really need a Dockerfile unless you have [other dependencies](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/recipes.html#using-mamba-install-or-pip-install-in-a-child-docker-image).

On host, create folder for notebooks...

`notebooks/src/plots.py`

```
def foobar():
    print('Hello from plots')
```

In compose, mount it under the working directory `/home/jovyan/work`

```
notebook:
    image: jupyter/scipy-notebook
    ...
    volumes:
      - ./notebooks:/home/jovyan/work
```

Load up the Jupyter environment, and create a notebook in the work folder, and then import the module.

```
from src import plots
plots.foobar()  # Hello from plots
```

This is the same workflow you'd do on your host if you weren't using Docker or Jupyter, so neither of those are really the problem.