# Python No module name import when I try to package my script to .exe

Tags: python, exe

I try to package my python script to executable :

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["sample.src.util.lib"]}

setup(
    name="Myprogram",
    version="0.1",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=[Executable("main.py")],
)
```

When I run `python setup() build`

Error :

```
ImportError: No module named 'sample.src.util.lib'
```

**EDIT** : 
Tree of my project

```
main.py
sample
   src
      util
          lib
              extract.py
              control.py
```

Comment: Where is `sample.src.util.lib` physically located in relation to the present python script?

Comment: Have you checked this thread?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named?rq=1