# Errors when running python3 manage.py syncdb to sync databases in my django application

Tags: python-3.x, django, migration, manage.py

Hi I am pretty new to django and I ended up with a very big error when I tried running the command python3 manage.py syncdb. I am trying to create a form builder application and encountered the error when I was trying to sync the database with the project. I am using the django-forms-builder from pypi.org.

For the error:

```
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you forgot to add `foo` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in project settings file?

Answer (score 0):

You must have forgotten to install a dependency that is listed in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Try `pip install foo`. Or you can remove `foo` from the installed apps.

Comment: The thing is there is no 'foo' in the installed apps and there is no library called foo that we can download with pip. Already went through both of the options.

Comment: i  that case this might be helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named