# Cannot import utils.programs but import utils successfully - python3 import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am trying to implement the code in https://github.com/kexinyi/ns-vqa.

However, when I try the command, `python tools/preprocess_questions.py \ ...` in the section of "Getting started". I see a message `No module named 'utils.programs'`.

Then I install `utils` and which makes `import utils` work, but `import utils.programs` does not work.

Does anyone have any idea to solve it?

```py
import os
import argparse
import json

import h5py
import numpy as np

import utils.programs as program_utils # this one cannot be imported
import utils.preprocess as preprocess_utils
import utils.utils as utils
```

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` or `computer-vision` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` in the folder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named

Comment: I don't know why you installed `utils` package because the mention code is not importing that, but it's importing `utils` folder's modules, check `reason` folder and there you're gonna find it. Probably there's a conflict because both of them have the same named, try to desinstall the package and try to run it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Add the below lines at the beginning of `preprocess_questions.py` file.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "..")
```

This should solve your problem.

**Explanation:**

It is failing because `preprocess_questions.py` don't know about the path of `utils.programs` to import. With the above lines added to the path using `..`, the required file will be imported.

For more on this refer how importing works in python.