# Trying to excute python file with CMD but always get no module named

Tags: python

I want to open my Python file through CMD. This file uses the Selenium module, but when I try to execute it in CMD, I get an error saying 'No Module named 'selenium'.' However, I have already installed the Selenium module, and when I execute it in an editor like Visual Studio Code, the code runs fine. What could be wrong?

Comment: Is the python binary that you use in the CMD the same python binary as associated in the VS Code environment?

Comment: Your editor may use virtual environments (venv) for managing dependencies and Python versions. A dependency like selenium installed in a venv may not me available globally or in another venv. Check that you activated the right environment before trying to run your script.

Comment: Execute `pip freeze` to check the versions of your libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question could be a duplicate of [Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named?rq=2)

HINT: if you have installed the Selenium module successfully but are encountering an error when running your Python file through CMD, it is likely due to a mismatch between the Python environment being used by CMD and the one used by Visual Studio Code.

1. To check your python environment just launch in your CMD

> python --version

and check that it displays the correct Python version.

2. In Visual Studio Code, you can check the Python interpreter used by opening the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and searching for "Python: Select Interpreter." Ensure that the same Python environment is selected in both places.