# How to resolve "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'storages.backends.azure_storage'"

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-blob-storage, django-storage

I have a django app and I have the module: django-storages[azure] installed with the command: pip install django-storages[azure]

And now I try to run the collectstatic command. But if I enter the command: python manage.py collectstatic

I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage\handler.py", line 35, in __getitem__
    return self._storages[alias]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'staticfiles'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage\handler.py", line 52, in create_storage
    storage_cls = import_string(backend)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 30, in import_string      
    return cached_import(module_path, class_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 15, in cached_import      
    module = import_module(module_path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\storages\backends\custom_azure.py", line 1, in <module>
    from storages.backends.azure_storage import AzureStorage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'storages.backends.azure_storage'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv     
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 184, in handle
    if self.is_local_storage() and self.storage.location:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 245, in is_local_storage
    return isinstance(self.storage, FileSystemStorage)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 280, in __getattribute__      
    value = super().__getattribute__(name)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 251, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 540, in _setup     
    self._wrapped = storages[STATICFILES_STORAGE_ALIAS]
                    ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage\handler.py", line 43, in __getitem__  
    storage = self.create_storage(params)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Riley\lost-and-found-system\shadow\Lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage\handler.py", line 54, in create_storage
    raise InvalidStorageError(f"Could not find backend {backend!r}: {e}") from e
django.core.files.storage.handler.InvalidStorageError: Could not find backend 'storages.backends.custom_azure.AzureStaticStorage': No module named 
'storages.backends.azure_storage'
```

i have checked the import paths and i can go to the definition of the classes in my editor

```
(shadow)
USER@DESKTOP-7TEEU5T MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Riley/lost-and-found-system 
$ ls
findit/  manage.py*  media/  README.md  requirements.txt  shadow/  static/  staticfiles/  storages/  Team1/
(shadow) 
USER@DESKTOP-7TEEU5T MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Riley/lost-and-found-system 
$ cd storages
(shadow) 
USER@DESKTOP-7TEEU5T MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Riley/lost-and-found-system/storages 
$ cd backends
(shadow) 
USER@DESKTOP-7TEEU5T MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Riley/lost-and-found-system/storages/backends
$ ls
__init__.py  __pycache__/  custom_azure.py
```

my settings.py file looks like

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.custom_azure.AzureMediaStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.custom_azure.AzureStaticStorage'
STATIC_LOCATION = 'static'
MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{STATIC_LOCATION}/'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{MEDIA_LOCATION}/'
```

and in my storages/backends/custom_azure.py file i have

```
from storages.backends.azure_storage import AzureStorage

class AzureMediaStorage(AzureStorage):
    ...

class AzureStaticStorage(AzureStorage):
    ...
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named/43731647#43731647) on the linked duplicate. You're shadowing the package you've installed by naming your own package `storages`, rename your directory to something other than "storages"