For using the files in other folder outside of dags, inside dags/ folder in apache airflow
I have the structure of folder as:
folder_structure
I want to use files which are present in deps folder in the dag files present in dags folder, how to do that?
Can someone please help me with this
I tried adding these lines of code in kafka_dag.py and parallel_tasks_dag.py for accessing those files in deps folder,
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../deps')))

from deps.packages.util.utilities import get_data, process_data

And I also added this line in airflow.cfg file:
pythonpath = /home/user1/airflow/deps


since you have not shared any error logs, I am not sure if this is the exact problem, but I think you are having trouble accessing the functions under deps. One potential reason for this may be that the deps folder is not added as a python package, init.py does not appear in the screenshot you posted. You can check the structure of your deps folder. Other than that, the code you added looks correct, I hope it works. For more please see

Hi, I have the init.py file in the screenshot I provided and the import error log I am getting is like: No module named 'deps' and the dags are not created because of the import errors.

hi @PavithraNagaYallapu , you have init.py files under root and dags but not in deps. I belive deps is added like normal folder, not a python package. Please see this related to your error log: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named
